# My food is very low

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've been playing fallout shelter for more than a week now but I've come across a problem.

Basically, my food has been very very low recently which makes my dwellers unhappy. I have 5 dwellers working in one big (three diners put together) diner. Why is my production rate so low?

Also I've done quite a few quests with the same dwellers because they are my good ones but when I want to choose three dwellers it misses out one of my normal adventurers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The food thing: Check the SPECIAL stats of your dwellers, and assign those with a high Agility to the kitchen. When you grab a Dweller and hover them over the kitchen you will either see (A 3) if there's a free spot available for them to work, or (A+2) if their Agility is higher than that of another Dweller working there. They will then swap places.

If your Dwellers all do not have high Agility scores, try equipping them with armor that raises it. These can be found by sending other Dwellers out to explore the wasteland (not the same as going on a quest! see below). Also, you can build a gym in which Dwellers can train their Agility. You will need at least 24 Dwellers to unlock that building.

2) When you select a quest, you'll see what level your Dwellers need before you can accept it. I assume your 'missing adventurer' is not of a high enough level.

Note that this is not the same as exploring the Wasteland; You can grab a dweller and put them on the ground outside the Vault to have them go exploring. Equip them with a weapon, armor and Stimpaks/Radaway when you do though. The Wasteland 's a tough place...

Answer (score 1):

**It all depends on how many people you have in your vault, how many people are working in the dinner and how high is their Agility.**

Also, from what you're saying, you're using the same people that are working in the dinner for quests. This means that your dinner food production is very low. I mean the actual production is the same but because the dinner has only 2 people means they need way more time.

**Another tip would be to reassign dwellers according to your needs**. If you need food then you reassign people to the dinner regardless of their Agility score (of course, try to find people that have as high Agility as possible). You can always **help yourself by equipping these dwellers with appropriate outfits**.

Have fun!